# Replacing leading characters in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would i replace first two characters if they are zeros?

Example:

```
 1. 00001
 2. 00123
 3. 02451
```

Should be:

```
 1. 11001
 2. 11123
 3. 02451
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention i need this in select clause (in a view)
Thanx.

Comment: What's the rule? Is it just '00'->'11', or something more complex(i.e. the same sample data could be given for "if the first two digits are zero, replace them both with the first non-zero digit")?

Comment: well ... in my case i know what to replace them with. I just want to do the replacing if the values have two zeros in the front. If not then no replacement is required.

Comment: Yes, but *we didn't* know what to replace them with. Most people assumed in their answers that it was just to replace them with `11`, and so they could write and *test* their answers based on that assumption. But if there was a more complex rule, you hadn't articulated it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
update  YourTable
set     col1 = '11' + substring(col1, 3, len(col1)-2)
where   col1 like '00%'
```

In a view, you could do it like:

```
select   case
         when col1 like '00%' then stuff(col1, 1, 2, '11')
         else col1
         end
from     YourTable;
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f4af/4/2)

Comment: Just a note, the substring should be "substring(col1, **3**, len(col1)-2)"because you want to start at 3rd character and the characters are numbered from 1, not 0.

Answer (score 9):

```
declare @a varchar(10)

select @a='01123'

Select case when LEFT(@a,2)='00' then STUFF(@a,1,2,'11') else @a end
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also use left method like below

```
select case When left(Name,2) = '00' Then stuff(Name, 1, 2, '11')
     else Name
     end
 from YourTable
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(MyCol,2),'00','11')+RIGHT(MyCol,3)
```